# how to pass data from one route component to another route component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vue-props

I'm trying to pass data from one route component - `UserList.vue` to another route component - `CreateUser.vue` in vue.js
but getting *undefined* when I try to access passed data inside destination component.

routes :

```
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'main',
    component: InitialView,
    children: [{
      path: '/',
      alias: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: () => import('../components/LogIn.vue')
    }]
  },
  {
    path: '/u',
    name: 'u',
    component: () => import('../views/MainView.vue'),
    children: [{
      path: 'users',
      alias: 'users',
      name: 'users',
      component: () => import('../views/UsersView.vue'),
      children: [{
        path: 'create-user',
        name: 'create_user',
        component: () => import('../components/CreateUser.vue')
      }, {
        path: 'list',
        alias: '',
        name: 'users_list',
        component: () => import('../components/UserList.vue')
      }, {
        path: 'edit',
        name: 'edit_user',
        component: () => import('../components/CreateUser.vue'),
        props: true,
      }]
    },
```

UserList.vue :

```
 <router-link :to="{
    name: 'edit_user', 
    params: {
       'userId': 'some',   
       'data' : "newUser"                                 
    }
 }">
```

CreateUser.vue :

```
props: ['userId', 'data'],
```

I'm trying to access `userId` and `data` in `CreateUser.vue` as `this.userId` and `this.data`

I have already referred many similar questions but nothing seems to work

Comment: I don’t have time to write a full answer. I’ll try tongive you some direction. You should not use params for that, but `query`. And than use the function mode in your routes file. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode

Comment: that will make all data visible in url;  I don't want that to happen, is there any way around ?

Comment: Params are also visible in the url. Look into `route.meta`. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html

Comment: is there any way I can share data between two separate route components `secretly` ?

Comment: What do you mean by secretly? In general there are no secrets in a Vue app. The users can see all the data in the app if they know how to do it. However, if you use meta data  in the route, a normal user will not be aware of that. If it is about having data available app wide, you might look into a store like Pinia.

Comment: by secretly I mean that data being pass should not be visible in UI as it do when passed in query in URL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248330/discussion-between-gabe-and-ht006).